# Статистический массив в С++ ведет себя неадекватно

Tags: c

Хотелось бы знать, как в С++ объявлять глобальные массивы в функции main?
Код мой программы такой:

```
int factorize(long long x) {
    static long* prime;
    long index = 0, n = prime[index];
    while (n * n <= x) {
       // ...
};

int main() {
    long* prime = (long*) malloc(51100000);
    // ....  
};
```

Когда программа доходит до строки "n = prime[index]", получается segmentation fault.

Comment: Никак. Область видимости переменных, объявленных внутри функции, ограничена фигурными скобками. Передавайте через новый аргумент функции. А статических массивов в этой программе вообще нет. И определитесь с языком С и С++ - это две большие разницы.

Comment: переменная `prime` в `main` и в `factorize` - разные. А в `factorize` вы переменную никакое значение не поставили.

Comment: 1. Это С или С++? Заголовок и тег не совпадают. Если C++, то руками вызывать `malloc` не стоит, лучше взять `std::vector` или в крайнем случае `new`. 2. Это не глобальная переменная, а статическая.

Comment: `static long* prime` - это `nullptr`. А вот это `prime[0]` - его разыменование. Что вы ожидали?

Answer (score 3):

`static long* prime;` в функции `factorize` и `long*prime` в `main` — две очень большие разницы...

Для языка С:

```
int factorize(long long x) {
    static long* prime = NULL;
    if (prime == NULL) prime = malloc(51100000);
    long index = 0, n = prime[index];
    while (n * n <= x) {
       // ...
};
```

Как-то так (не знаю, точно ли вам нужна именно такая память...). `malloc` будет вызван один раз, при первом обращении к функции `factorize` (хотя, если вызов будет неуспешен, то будет вызываться при каждом вызове :)).

Да, о терминологии... Здесь "статическая" переменная-указатель `prime`, но не массив, память для которого выделяется динамически.

P.S. В С++ можно

```
    static long* prime = NULL;
    if (prime == NULL) prime = malloc(51100000);
```

заменить на

```
    static long* prime = (long*)malloc(51100000);
```